# Insert in a dropdownlist a line to separate two intervas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

i have a dropdownlist filled with the 24 hours.
After the 12:00 i want to insert a line to differentiate two timeslice.
How can i do?

Thanks

Comment: There is not dropdownlist control in WPF.  Do you mean ComboBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're hard coding the values then something like this will do the trick:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
        <!-- ... -->
        <ComboBoxItem Content="10:00"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="11:00"/>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem.Content>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                    <TextBlock Text="12:00" Margin="0,0,0,1"/>
                </Border>
            </ComboBoxItem.Content>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="13:00"/>
        <!-- ... -->
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Phil for your response. I've forgotten that my hard problem is that the separator is dynamic and it's possible to set it.

Comment: @user1771347 Do you need any more help with that, and what do you mean by dynamic, visible/not visible?

Answer (score 0):

I found online this trick...and it works!!!
in my XAML i have introduced this code snippet:

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}"
         BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}"
                   Value="">
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
              <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                         IsEnabled="False" />
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Then in my code behind i have insered a brand new blank item not editable.
The result is a line under the item pre-selected.
My goal is reached.

I hope this might help someone (also me in future :) )